# Android USB C phone not working without adapter

Tags: macos, usb, android

My Android USB C phone (Google Pixel) is not recognised by 2016 MacBook Pro (macOS Sierra 10.12.2 and Multiport driver installed) as long as no adapter is plugged in at the same time.

It is working when

- the phone is plugged into the adapter using a Standard USB A to USB C cable
- the phone is plugged into the MacBook directly using an USB C cable and an adapter (e.g. Multiport adapter or simple Standard USB A to USB C adapter) is plugged in beside. The phone is NOT connected to the adapter (nothing is plugged into the adapter).

Is there a known way to resolve this problem?

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: @patrix tried to clarify, thx

Comment: Did you ever understood this behavior? I feel like I have a similar issue now: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418412/ethernet-over-usb-not-working-with-usb-c-to-usb-c-cable-working-with-adapter