# usb-c SD card reader works only if connected via usb-c to usb-a adapter (for a short time), flawless on other OS

Tags: usb, crash, kernel, sd-card

I have two "survival kits" with USB cables, adapters, etc. on a credit-card size phone cradle. Very nice gizmo ... The two of them have an SD card reader built in, and both of them are giving me trouble on my Mac Book Pro 13" Late 2020.

These card readers have been tested on Debian 11 on my other laptop and work just fine there. Also my USB-C Samsung phones work fine with these readers, only my Mac seems to have issues with these readers (same cables, adapters and same SD-cards).

I am trying to debug what's wrong with mac OS and these simple card readers.

The issue is similar for the two card readers, so I will describe them as one.
The card reader is not recognized at all when I connect it on USB-C directly.

Instead, if I connect the card reader `via a USB-A to USB-C adapter` the OS usually sees my SD card as a new volume. That's very strange to me, how adding an adapter can impact on the hardware being recognized at all? Most times after a minute or two the system complain that I have improperly disconnected the drive, even though it is still connected. I presume it's connection through a USB-A to USB-C is not so stable after all.

When connected via the USB-A adapter this is how the hardware is seen by `sudo system_profiler SPUSBDataType`

```
    USB 3.1 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleIntelICLUSBXHCI
      PCI Device ID: 0x38ed
      PCI Revision ID: 0x0010
      PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086

        MXT USB Device:

          Product ID: 0x8816
          Vendor ID: 0xaaaa
          Version: 13.08
          Serial Number: 150101v01
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
          Manufacturer: MXTronics
          Location ID: 0x14300000 / 3
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 100
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
          Media:
            Storage Device:
              Capacity: 256,09 GB (256.087.425.024 bytes)
              Removable Media: Yes
              BSD Name: disk2
              Logical Unit: 0
              Partition Map Type: MBR (Master Boot Record)
              S.M.A.R.T. status: Verified
              USB Interface: 0
              Volumes:
                usbcard:
                  Capacity: 256,09 GB (256.086.376.448 bytes)
                  Free: 250,57 GB (250.566.803.456 bytes)
                  Writable: Yes
                  File System: ExFAT
                  BSD Name: disk2s1
                  Mount Point: /Volumes/usbcard
                  Content: Windows_NTFS
                  Volume UUID: 6D51DB39-8C01-364E-A00D-F9EA2A9EE682
```

In the `Console` app I can see some messages related to this hardware. I know from Linux that it is called `MXT` and searching this term I get

```
default 16:24:14.885163+0200    kernel  HS04@14400000: AppleUSBHostPort::enumerateDeviceComplete_block_invoke: enumerated 0xaaaa/8816/1308 (MXT USB Device / 50) at 480 Mbps
error   16:24:14.885216+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: controller <private> (XHC1) usbService <private> (MXT USB Device) options 0x00000000
error   16:24:14.885248+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallGated: IOUSBHostDevice <private> (MXT USB Device)
error   16:24:14.886010+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: registering MXT USB Device@14400000 (<private>) for matching
default 16:24:15.000612+0200    icdd                   Added | 0x10001ace - [USB][      MXT USB Device ] ( 0, 0, 0) @ 0x14400000 |
default 16:24:15.074418+0200    icdd                Inferior | 0x10001acf - [USB][      MXT USB Device ] ( 8, 6,50) @ 0x14400000 |
default 16:24:15.415729+0200    kernel  HS04@14400000: AppleUSBHostPort::terminateDevice: destroying 0xaaaa/8816/1308 (MXT USB Device): connect change interrupt
default 16:24:15.417227+0200    kernel  Android File Tra@(null): AppleUSBHostUserClient::openGated: could not open provider MXT USB Device. provider already opened for exclusive access by a kernel client
default 16:24:15.418447+0200    icdd               [Removed] | [USB][      MXT USB Device ] ( 0, 0, 0) @ 0x14400000 |
default 16:24:15.418565+0200    icdd               [Removed] | [USB][      MXT USB Device ] ( 8, 6,50) @ 0x14400000 |
default 16:24:15.420450+0200    kernel  USB device AAAA881614400000 - MXTronics, MXT USB Device - detected termination of interfaceNub, currentPowerState 1, provider is IOUSBMassStorageInterfaceNub
default 16:24:16.609042+0200    kernel  HS04@14400000: AppleUSBHostPort::enumerateDeviceComplete_block_invoke: enumerated 0xaaaa/8816/1308 (MXT USB Device / 57) at 480 Mbps
error   16:24:16.609110+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: controller <private> (XHC1) usbService <private> (MXT USB Device) options 0x00000000
error   16:24:16.609153+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallGated: IOUSBHostDevice <private> (MXT USB Device)
error   16:24:16.609786+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: registering MXT USB Device@14400000 (<private>) for matching
default 16:24:16.677778+0200    icdd                   Added | 0x10001ad1 - [USB][      MXT USB Device ] ( 0, 0, 0) @ 0x14400000 |
default 16:24:16.792480+0200    icdd                Inferior | 0x10001ad2 - [USB][      MXT USB Device ] ( 8, 6,50) @ 0x14400000 |
```

When connected directly via USB-C I see very little under `MXT`

```
error   16:26:26.676142+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: controller <private> (XHC1) usbService <private> (MXT USB Device) options 0x00000000
error   16:26:26.676175+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallGated: IOUSBHostDevice <private> (MXT USB Device)
error   16:26:26.676812+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: registering MXT USB Device@14400000 (<private>) for matching
```

something more on the search for `USB`

```
error   16:26:25.538300+0200    kernel  AppleIntelUSBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::waitForCommand: command 0x000000000038a000 0x0000000034002c01 got result 0x0000000000381eb0 0x0400000034008401 after 0ms
error   16:26:25.538330+0200    kernel  AppleIntelUSBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::setAddress: completed with result code 4
error   16:26:25.538356+0200    kernel  AppleIntelUSBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::waitForCommand: command 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000034013c01 got result 0x0000000000381ec0 0x0b00000034008401 after 0ms
error   16:26:25.538361+0200    kernel  AppleIntelUSBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::stopEndpoint: completed with result code 11
error   16:26:26.670424+0200    kernel  AppleUSBXHCIDevice: AppleUSBXHCIDevice::transferEvent: no endpoint 1 for event 0x0000000000437200 1b000000 35018001
error   16:26:26.676129+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallback: controller <private> (XHC1) usbServiceArray <private>(count 1) options 0x00000000
error   16:26:26.676137+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallback: [0] <private>
error   16:26:26.676142+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: controller <private> (XHC1) usbService <private> (MXT USB Device) options 0x00000000
error   16:26:26.676167+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::getOrCreateLegacyControllerGated: located existing AppleUSBController@14000000
error   16:26:26.676175+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCallGated: IOUSBHostDevice <private> (MXT USB Device)
error   16:26:26.676197+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::addDeviceToUsbPlane:
error   16:26:26.676796+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: usbServiceCallbackGated completed with 0x00000000 and service <private>
error   16:26:26.676812+0200    kernel  AppleUSBLegacyRoot@(null): AppleUSBLegacyRoot::usbServiceCall: registering MXT USB Device@14400000 (<private>) for matching
error   16:26:26.741914+0200    kernel  AppleUSBXHCIRequest: AppleUSBXHCIRequest::finish: transfer completed with status 0xe00002ed
error   16:26:26.843353+0200    kernel  XHC1@14000000: AppleUSBHostController::clearPipeStall: pipe <private> completed with 0xe00002d8
error   16:26:26.843384+0200    kernel  AppleUSBHostRequestCompleter::clearPipeStallThreadCall: clearStall for pipe <private> failed (0xe00002d8)
error   16:26:26.843791+0200    kernel  XHC1@14000000: AppleUSBHostController::suspendPipes: device <private> completed with 0xe00002f0
```

I read that other people have found [funny behavior of USB-c peripherals](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/418412/ethernet-over-usb-not-working-with-usb-c-to-usb-c-cable-working-with-adapter) on Mac OS when compared to other OS, [sometimes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452895/sandisk-1tb-portable-ssd-not-recognized-as-disk-when-connected-directly-usb-c-to) related to cables. I doubt cables are my issue here, as I tried several, including Apple's and anyway tested on other devices.

Given all this how can I debug the recognition of this hardware being failed on USB-C and begin unstable on UBC-C to USB-A converter?

FYI The other card reader is seen by Linux as "Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE", but when it is seen by Mac OS (via USB-A)   is seen as a

```
       
          Product ID: 0x0727
          Vendor ID: 0x05e3  (Genesys Logic, Inc.)
          Version: 2.50
          Serial Number: 000000000250
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
          Manufacturer: Generic
          Location ID: 0x14400000 / 40
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 500
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```